# Image not displayed in postman (readable) using Laravel API

Tags: laravel, postman

The image is saved to the database and file path specified in the response. Trying to display the image or download it, it is not the displayed. I tried to read the same image but it is working.

```
storage_path('app/uploads/images/3.png')
```

I read the 3.png stored in the directory and it is working without displaying error but to display the image it doesn't display image.

```
[![if (empty($imag)){
        return response()->json(\[
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'There was a problem creating the postcard!'
        \], 201);
    }
    return response()->json(\[
        'success' => true,
        'data' => file_get_contents(storage_path('app/public/uploads/images/'.$exportName)),
        'message' => 'Postcard created successfully!'
    \],200);
    }
```

The directory where the image is saved is storage/app/public/uploads/ 
I used php artisan storage:link

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your storage path is

App/upload/images/3.png

And you are uploding image in

App/upload/public/images/3.png

So database is storing above path and image is not uploded in above path

Just remove public from above path it works...

Comment: Though I have figured out the solution. I have changed the path from storage to public in filesystem.php. Thanks